# Differences and relations between $\partial x, dx, \delta x, \Delta x$.

Tags: derivatives, notation, partial-derivative, differential-forms

$\partial x, dx, \delta x, \Delta x$ all describe the change of something, but what distinguishes them, and when is this distinction irrelevant?

For instance, sometimes $\dfrac{\mathrm df(x)}{\mathrm dx} = \dfrac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}$, and in thermodynamics the equality $pdV = \delta W$ might hold. So when is it important to distinguish these, and when can they be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think they mean the following:

$\partial$ symbol refers to a partial derivative. It is used in multivariate calculus, when you have more than one variable. As an example, when having a function $f=f(x,y)$ the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to one of its variables is noted by 
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\qquad or \qquad \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$$

$d$ symbol, refers to a total derivative. It is used almost everywhere. For example the internal energy $u$ can be expressed as a total derivative as a function of the variables on which it depends: the entropy and the density as follows
$$du = \frac{\partial u}{\partial s}\bigg|_{\rho}\,ds+\frac{\partial u}{\partial \rho}\bigg|_{s}\,d\rho$$
the general way to say this, compactly is 
$$dF({\bf x}) = {\bf grad}F({\bf x})\cdot d{\bf x}$$

$\delta$ symbol mostly refers to a inexact differential, that depends for example on the path of integration 
$$\delta W = -p(V,T)\,dV$$
or if the applied force is conservative, or the expansion process isobaric
$$dW = -mg\,dz\qquad dW = -p\,dV$$
the inexatc differential turns into an exact one.

$\Delta$ symbol usually refers to a macroscopic change (contrary to differential), for example 
$$\Delta U = \int_{U_1}^{U_2}{dU}$$

Comment: Nice and clear answer. For your example about $\delta W$, I think $p$ should be a function of at least another variable than $V$ (for instance $p(V,T)$) for $\delta W = pdV$ to be an inexact differential.

Comment: Completely true @TheQuark . I've changed that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

$Δx$ is about a [secant line,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_line) a line between two points representing the rate of change between those two points. That's a "differential" (between the two points).

$dx$ is about a [tangent line](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TangentLine.html) to one point, representing an instantaneous rate of change. That makes it a "derivative."

$δx$ is about a tangent line to a [partial derivative.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative) That's a rate of change or derivative in one direction, holding a number of other directions constant.

$\partial x$ is used to denote partial derivative when you have a multivariate function (e.g. one with $x,y,w$, instead of just $x$ alone).

Comment: For $\Delta$ you probably mean it is an "increment" (not a "differential")? And in the case of a secant line between two points, one would probably rather talk about the _average_ rate of change between those two points.

Comment: I don't clearly see the difference in explanation between the $\delta$ and the $\partial$. I think $\delta$ is rather used to indicate inexact differentials as explained by [HBR](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2049508)